# Regexp string only also founds special chars

Tags: html, regex, validation

Can't figure it out, why my regexp founds not only alpha chars?

The pattern:

```
([\<])([^\>]{1,})([a-zA-Z])([\>])
```

The example

```
-------- Original Message --------
Subject:    This is plain test
Date:   Tue, 04 Jun 2013 13:26:04 +0000
From:   Hello there <myemail@myemail.tld>
To:     myemail@myemail.tld <myemail@myemail.tld>

Hello! This is plain mail!
<SP@AN></SPA@N>
No html is inserted. No no!
<man2></man2>
Why do you found this < something inside this>???
```

Expression found email addresses and invalid html tags!
I need, so no invalid tags and no email address will be matched due to parsing text for html valid tags.
What is wrong with this patter and why this matches invalid tags and emails?

Here is the link for my tests. http://regexr.com?353v9

Comment: You'll need to tell us what you want to match and what is wrong with what it matches now if you want better help on how to fix your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple one should suit your needs:

```
</?[a-zA-Z0-9]+?>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?3541b)

Answer (score 0):

Your second group `([^\>]{1,})` finds one or more characters which are not closing angle brackets `>` — this includes letters, numerals, and, well, everything that's not a `>`. I believe that's why your matches are not what you are expecting; it's hard to know since you haven't told what exactly you're trying to match, what strings the pattern does match, or what is wrong with the matches.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want to filter out stuff like `< > @ /` ?

If that is the case you could use `^[^\<\>\/\\\'\"]*$` to match *everything* except `< > / \ ' "`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your regex (groups):

1. `([\<])` = exactly one `<`
2. `([^\>]{1,})` = **any** character that is *not* a `>`, one or more times
3. `([a-zA-Z])` = exactly one lowercase or uppercase alphabetic character
4. `([\>])` = exactly one `>`

That's why email addresses like `<myemail@myemail.tld>` are matched:

1. `<`
2. `myemail@myemail.tl`
3. `d`
4. `>`

And tag-like strings like `<SPA@N>`:

1. `<`
2. `SPA@`
3. `N`
4. `>`

or `< something inside this>`:

1. `<`
2. `something inside thi` (including the space at the beginning)
3. `s`
4. `>`

`<man2>` does not match, because the number `2` before the `>` is not an alpha character.

Basic solution: To match typical HTML tags, you could use `([\<]\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\>])`

1. `([\<]\/?)` = one `<` or `</` (for closing tags)
2. `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` = one or more alphanumeric (to support `<h2>` etc) characters – the HTML element name
3. `([\>])` = one `>`

Note this does not support XHTML empty tag notation like `<br />` or `<br/>`, nor tags with attributes like `<a href="http://example.com">`. There are many regex resources out there with a bunch of patterns for HTML tags, email address validation, etc.

**Edit:** If you're doing any filtering, be sure not to just strip out `>` characters as these are commonly used in plain text email messages to indicate quote blocks when replying.